# How to use a secret from AzureKeyVault into PowerShell -Credential?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, virtual-machine, powershell-remoting

```
      - task: AzureKeyVault@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'mySub'
          KeyVaultName: 'myVault'
          SecretsFilter: 'myPass'
          RunAsPreJob: false
```

I can do this to make sure the password is correct, which it is.

```
echo $(myPass) > secret.txt
```

This is how I use it in a separate task:

```
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
            targetType: inline
            script: |
                $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $(myPass) -AsPlainText -Force
                $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "administrator", $password
                 Invoke-Command -VMName "myVM" -ScriptBlock {
                     Write-Host "Hello!"
                     systeminfo
                 } -Credential $cred
        displayName: 'Remoting into a computer.'
```

I get this error:

```
The credential is invalid.
```

How do I use that password I get from the keyvault to get onto the VM?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Comment: It turned out my problem had nothing to do with credential rather that the remote hadn't boot up yet. Your answer doesn't  however address the question as you can use keyVault secrets without mapping them. At least this is what I did!  check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-new-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

From your YAML sample, you are using the Key Vault secret in Pipeline. When you download the Key vault secret, it will save as secret variable in Pipeline.

To use the secret variable in Azure Pipeline, you need to explicitly map secret variables in Agent Job.

In your case, you need to add environment variable in PowerShell task to map secret variables.

Here is an example:

```
- powershell: |
   echo $(myPass)
   
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  env:
    myPass: $(myPass)
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Secret Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)